# How to download a webpage that require username and password?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

For example, I want to download this page after inserting username and password:

```
http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/
```

I have tryed with wget but doesn't work.

Is there a solution with python ?

You can test with these username and password:

```
username: johnconnor
password: hellohello
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [wget with authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication)

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+urllib2+form  Search helps.  Use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Authentication with urllib2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014570/python-authentication-with-urllib2)

Comment: Not duplicate of "Python Authentication with urllib2" - this site uses "forms-based" authentication, not HTTP basic or digest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @robert says, use mechanize.

To get you started:

```
from mechanize import Browser
b = Browser()
b.open("http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/index.php")
b.select_form(nr=0)
b["user"] = "johnconnor"
b["passwrd"] = "hellohello"
b.submit()

response = b.response().read()
if "Salve <b>johnconnor</b>" in response:
    print "Logged in!"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) module and with that it is possible do to basic and form based authentication (with cookies support).

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://personalpages.tds.net/~kent37/kk/00010.html) on your issue.

Comment: I have just tryed it but doesn't work. See above in the question I have just insert username and password to test if you want :)

Comment: Go with mechanize then, as others seem to be recommending that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module.  It's basically a programmatic browser interface.