# Unable to download website's contents using mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I got a python script [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275955/how-to-download-a-webpage-that-require-username-and-password?lq=1) to download web contents from a course website:

```
from mechanize import Browser
b = Browser()
b.open("https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/cs498cc/Home")
b.select_form(nr=0)
b["user"] = "myusername"
b["passwrd"] = "blabla"
b.submit()

response = b.response().read()
if "Salve <b>johnconnor</b>" in response:
print "Logged in!"
```

I'm getting an error:

```
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'user'
```

I'm not sure how to do this since I've just started learning python and discovered that library.
I've tried using the --user=X --password=Y flags with wget too, but it only downloads the login page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form elements have different names:

```
<input type="text" name="os_username" id="os_username" class="text   " data-focus="0">
<input type="password" name="os_password" id="os_password" class="password ">
```

Change `user` to `os_username` and `passwrd` to `os_password` and it might work.

Comment: To no avail.. "no control matching name 'os_username'" :/

Comment: @Siddhartha: The first form is a search box. Change `b.select_form(nr=0)` to `b.select_form(nr=1)` and it should work.

Comment: It works! The script successfully runs. So i'm logged in now, how do get the contents of the website? I didn't find anything on google, I think i'm supposed to use b.retrieve()? Thanks!